# Flot charts y axis tick labels overlapping

Tags: jquery, flot

On both v0.8.3 and v0.8.2
y Axis tick labels are overlapping when the values are too close to each other
like 100 and 101, in a 0-150 range.

Is there any trick to make them properly visible ?
I cannot increase the height to 1500px to make them sitting each other.

[image]

Comment: I posted two different solutions, using JavaScript (Flot options) or CSS. Both have their advantages depending on how you generate your graph and the ticks themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need tick labels so close that they would overlap, you can use a second axis to seperate them, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5ord3nj/) for an example. Relevant code:

```
    yaxes: [{
        min: -1.2,
        max: 1.2,
        ticks: 8,
        show: true,
        position: 'left'
    },{
        min: -1.2,
        max: 1.2,
        ticks: 25,
        show: true,
        position: 'left',
        tickLength: 0,
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' // makes the axis transparent
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the Flot options, you can also use CSS to seperate the tick labels, for example by shifting odd and even tick labels to the left and right respectively. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxjfoz0r/) for an example. Relevant CSS code:

```
#placeholder div.flot-y-axis div.flot-tick-label:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 30px;  
}
#placeholder div.flot-y-axis div.flot-tick-label:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: 30px;  
}
```